# Can Rstudio run the code embedded inside a knitted html file produced by markdown?

Tags: r, rstudio, markdown

The question if needs further elaboration is this.
1. A rmd file is written
2. Rmd is knitted to html.
3. Html is saved with the code in it.
I need Rstudio to read the Html file, identify the code inside it and run it.
Is there a way?

Comment: This isn't exactly what you asked, but maybe in the right direction? https://ropensci.org/technotes/2018/10/01/tinkr/

Answer (score 3):

Assuming:

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

Blah Blah

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

```{r}
xdf <- rbind.data.frame(mtcars, mtcars)

library(tidyverse) # rly bad place to put this but it's just a demo

just6 <- filter(xdf, cyl == 6)
```

```{r}
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point()
```

```{r}
count(just6, gear)
```
````

and a file named "forso.Rmd" which is knit to "forso.html":

```
library(rvest)

pg <- read_html("forso.html")

html_nodes(pg, "pre.r") %>% 
  html_text() %>% 
  styler::style_text() %>%
  write_lines("my-recovered-r-code.R") %>% 
  cat(sep="\n")
## summary(cars)
## xdf <- rbind.data.frame(mtcars, mtcars)
## 
## library(tidyverse) # rly bad place to put this but it's just a demo
## just6 <- filter(xdf, cyl == 6)
## ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point()
## count(just6, gear)
```

The "`##`" above is just an artifact of the output.

**NOTE** that you *will not* be able to get `include=FALSE` or `echo=FALSE` code back (as the above demonstrates).

**Also NOTE** that the use of `styler` is 100% optional.